# run chrome's SpeechSynthesis on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Google did great job with chrome's **SpeechSynthesis**, It's much better then Microsoft's tts (and frankly any other free solution I found).

I wonder, is there any way to use Chrome's **SpeechSynthesis** over **node.js**?

Comment: how exactly do you want to use this?

Comment: Stream the output over http-request / file